# mq_open() API return Open Invalid argument

Tags: c, queue

1.this part of code return  "Open queue failed, error Invalid argument" , i don't understand why !!

2.code part

```
   struct mq_attr * attr = NULL  ;
   attr = (struct mq_attr * ) malloc (sizeof(struct mq_attr));
   attr->mq_maxmsg   = 100;
   attr->mq_msgsize  = sizeof(upgrademanager_event_t);
   upgrademanager->queue = mq_open("/upgrademanager_mqueue", O_RDWR|O_CREAT|O_EXCL, 0, & attr);                         
   if (upgrademanager->queue == (mqd_t)-1)
    TRACE_ERROR("Open queue failed, error %s. ", strerror(errno));
```

Comment: Your compiler isn't giving you a warning about that code?

Comment: Try a smaller value for `mq_msgsize`. (e.g.) Start with 1 and work upwards. Look at `man mq_overview`. Under linux, that will show how to use `/proc/sys/fs/mqueue/msg*` to look at max/default values. For example, the default value in `/proc/sys/fs/mqueue/msg_max` is 10 [_not_ 100]. As root, you can usually write to that file to increase the value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your process is not privileged i.e. you are not running it as root then most likely the mq_maxmsg value you are setting i.e. 100 is larger than the default value i.e. 10. Try changing the default value in /proc/sys/fs/mqueue/msg_max

You shouldn't see this issue if you're running as root since HARD_MSGMAX is 65536 (assuming you're running on Linux 3.5 and above).

Quoting from man page for mq_open:

> **EINVAL** O_CREAT was specified in oflag, and attr was not NULL, but attr->mq_maxmsg or attr->mq_msqsize was invalid.  Both of these fields must be greater than  zero.   In  a  process
>                 that  is unprivileged (does not have the CAP_SYS_RESOURCE capability), **attr->mq_maxmsg must be less than or equal to the msg_max limit**, and attr->mq_msgsize must be less than
>                 or equal to the msgsize_max limit.  In addition, even in a privileged process, attr->mq_maxmsg cannot exceed the HARD_MAX limit.  (See mq_overview(7)  for  details  of  these
>                 limits.)

Quoting from the man page for mq_overview:

> **/proc/sys/fs/mqueue/msg_max**
>                 This  file can be used to view and change the ceiling value for the maximum number of messages in a queue.  This value acts as a ceiling on the attr->mq_maxmsg argument given
>                 to mq_open(3).  The default value for msg_max is 10.  The minimum value is 1 (10 in kernels before 2.6.28).  The upper limit is HARD_MSGMAX.  The msg_max limit is ignored for
>                 privileged processes (CAP_SYS_RESOURCE), but the HARD_MSGMAX ceiling is nevertheless imposed.